# Error: mapbox-maps-ios could not be resolved

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager, mapbox-ios

I am trying to follow MapBox iOS SDK on my project through Swift package Manager dependency. Facing issue in setup.

**Followed MapBox Guidelines :**
https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/

**Error:** `mapbox-maps-ios could not be resolved`

**Steps already tried:**

- Cleaned up Derived data.
- Also tried to setup with new sample app, no luck for me.

**Error Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Please do the following to solve it:

Open your Terminal and enter:

1. cd
2. touch .netrc
3. open .netrc

Paste the following and ONLY replace PRIVATE_MAPBOX_API_TOKEN with your secrete Mapbox Api Token:

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password PRIVATE_MAPBOX_API_TOKEN
```

It now should look something like this. It is crucial that you do not include the "<>":

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password sk.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now give it another try :-)

Comment: This doesn't work!

Comment: In my case, the token created is the private one, and it needs to be setup with the Downloads:read permission

Comment: On Xcode `v14.2`, these instructions did work for me BUT, after setting up the `~/.netrc` file, I had to (a) reset the Package Caches (`File > Packages > Reset Package Caches`), and (b) restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @rtorres in the comments

1. Set up the .netrc
2. File > Packages > Reset Package Caches
3. Restart Xcode